# When I run rails db:migrate the migration doesn't fully work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class CreateMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :messages do |t|
      t.text :body
      t.integer :user_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

After running rails db:migrate my schema looks like this...

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2020_03_20_063104) do

  create_table "messages", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "username"
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

I am wondering where the `t.text "body"` is and where the `t.integer "user_id"`is and why it isn't showing up in my schema under messages table.

I have checked migration status and all migrations have been ran.

Comment: Try `rails db:migrate:redo` to rollback this migration (it would drop `messages` table) and do it again.

Comment: Is it only your `schema.rb` file that doesn't reflect the migration, or are those columns missing from your database table as well?

Comment: The ``` rails db:migrate:redo ``` worked! I swear I tried this before. Oh well it worked this time! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you ran something like this in your migration file

```rb
class CreateMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :messages do |t|
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Messages table is created and after this you can't create another migration with `create_table :messages`. Like @Marek Lipka wrote on comments. Either you need to rollback your `CreateMessages` migration and chance file and run your migration again. Or you need to write another migration to change existing table like this.

```rb
class AddBodyAndUserIdToMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :messages, :body, :text
    add_column :messages, :user_id, :integer
  end
end
```